# Can't update variable value in mongoose find method

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a variable's value in the findById mongoose method. The code looks like this:

```
let todayIncome = 0;

// Loop through all id's and add the price value to todayIncome 
for(let i = 0; i < priceIDs.length; i++) {
   Prices.findById({ _id: priceIDs[i] }, (err, data) => {
      todayIncome += data.price;
      console.log("INCOME: ", todayIncome) // Output is 40 which is correct
   });
}
        
console.log("Income: ", todayIncome); // Output is 0

// Return dayIncome a json
res.json({
   data: todayIncome // Output is 0
});
```

Why can't the value be saved in the variable outside of the findById method am I missing something? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked which one logs first?. Is it the inside or outside

Comment: @Vishnu good one! I see now that the one outside the loop is called first but why is that?

Comment: `findById` execute asynchronously and pass the results to the `callback` when it's ready. In your case for loops completes the iteration and executes the outside `console.log` before the `callback` for the `findById` method is called

Comment: @Vishnu thanks I have solved it! I made it asynchrous